fetching api data inside reducer func
getting output as promise in line 23
I am trying to fetch the data by using the usereducer of which the dispatcher func is called inside useeffect hook.but i get the output as promise what to do?
let initApi=null;
let apiReducer=async (curdata,perform)=>{
    if(perform=='fetch'){
        fetchData();
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

function Cloth() {
    let [clothapiData,apiDispatcher]=useReducer(apiReducer,initApi);
    useEffect(
        ()=>{
        apiDispatcher('fetch')
        }
    ,[])
    console.log(clothapiData);
    return (
    <div className='cloths'>
    {<video autoPlay src='../assets/22.gif'></video>}
    { clothapiData?clothapiData.map(({id,image,title,price})=>{
        return <NavLink to={`../../${id}`} className='cloth' key={id}>
            <div><img src={image} alt="" /></div>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <h4>₹{price}</h4>
        </NavLink>
    }): <h1>Loading...</h1> }
    </div>
    )
}


Generally speaking, "reducer" functions are to be considered pure, synchronous functions, and yours is neither.
Run the side-effect of fetching some data in the useEffect hook and then dispatch an action payload to your reducer.
Example Implementation:
const initialState = null;

const apiReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "setData":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const setData = (payload) => ({
  type: "setData",
  payload,
});

function Cloth() {
  const [clothApiData, apiDispatcher] = useReducer(apiReducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
      .then(data => {
        apiDispatcher(setData(data));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // catch and handle/ignore any rejections or thrown errors
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='cloths'>
      <video autoPlay src='../assets/22.gif' />
      {clothApiData
        ? clothApiData.map(({ id, image, title, price }) => (
          <NavLink to={`../../${id}`} className='cloth' key={id}>
            <div><img src={image} alt="" /></div>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <h4>₹{price}</h4>
          </NavLink>
        ))
        : <h1>Loading...</h1>
      }
    </div>
  );
};

